# Minimum for loop length for auto vectorization?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I am wondering what should be the minimum for loop length for the auto vectorizer to enable the vectorization. ?

for eg:

```
       for (int i= 0 ; i< 4 ; i+= 3)
        // Some operations
```

using Rpass flag, I am getting following remark.

```
loop control flow is not understood by vectorizer [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]
```

can someone help me understand what are the basic requirement for a for loop to get vectorized. ?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.  For something like an accumulate loop, the compiler should be able to easily vectorize a loop like `for (int i= 0; i< size; ++i)`

Comment: It really depends on your `// Some operations` too. But to vectorise if is nice to have independent iterations

Comment: https://easyperf.net/blog/2017/11/02/Vectorization_width